# Identifying $C_c(X)$ with $C_0(U)$ for $U \subseteq X$ open, relative compact

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I am currently learning for an exam and came across this sentence in a functional analysis script:

Let $X$ locally compact space, $C_c(X) = \{f:X\to \mathbb C: \operatorname{supp}(f) \text{ is compact}\}$ and $C_0(X) = \{f:X\to \mathbb C: \forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists K \subseteq X \text{ compact} : \vert f(x) \vert \leq \epsilon \text{ on } X \setminus K\}$.

"For an open and relatively compact subset $U \subseteq X$ the space $C_0(U)$ can
be identified naturally with a subspace of $C_c(X)$."

I really don't see how that works "naturally". I would appreciate some help :)

Comment: Nice result! ${}$

Comment: Well, every function in $C_0(U)$ is supported in $\overline{U}$, which is compact, right?

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan That makes sense. Thanks, I can't say why I haven't seen that. It's pretty obvious. :)

Comment: @Pralhad, Yaddle: a function  $f\in C_0(U)$ is only defined on $U$ and  $supp f\subset U$  **is not compact in general!**.  The subtle point is that $f\notin C_c(X)$ since $f$ is not defined outside of $U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C_{\bar U}(X)\subset C_c(X)$ be the set of continuous functions on $X$ with support in $\bar U$.
Then there exists an extension map   $$ext:C_0(U)\to   C_{\bar U}(X):f\mapsto extf$$ obtained by extending $f$ to points $x\in X\setminus U$ by decreeing that $(extf)(x)=0$.

We also have a restriction map $$res:   C_{\bar U}(X)\to C_0(U):f\mapsto res f=f\vert U                        $$
 The map $ext$ thus identifies, as required,  $C_0(U)$ with the subspace $C_{\bar U}(X)$ of $C_c(X)$ the inverse identification being given by $res$.

**Note carefully**
We have $C_0(U) = \{f:U\to \mathbb C: \forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists K \subseteq U \text{ compact} : \vert f(x) \vert \leq \epsilon \text{ on } U \setminus K\}$
So, a function $f\in C_0(U)$ has  $\operatorname {supp}f\subset U$ but that support **is not compact in general**: try to find an example!
Be sure to understand that point while reading the answer.